# linq-to-xml syntax error: retrieve attribute value

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-xml

I am Loading xml and need to retrieve the main element's attribute id

example xml:

[image]

I need to get listing id's value using linq and then Street Name

I think I need to use DescendantsAndSelf since it is the main element

```
XElement source = XElement.Load("...");
var listing = (from details in source.DescendantsAndSelf()
               where details.Attribute("id").Value == "8225706"
               select new ListVM
               {
                 Street = details.Element("Address").Element("Street") 
               }).ToList();
```

fails on 3rd line - "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."  Please advice what is wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is your `details.Attribute("id").Value` will fail for all elements which don't have 'id' attribute, since you are invoking 'Value' property on Null reference.

Add `details.Attribute("id") != null` check before comparing the values.

Your query should look like:-

```
 var listing = (from details in source.DescendantsAndSelf()
                           where details.Attribute("id") != null && details.Attribute("id").Value == "8225706"
                           select new 
                           {
                               Street = details.Element("Address").Element("Street")
                           }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, It works. The source contains only one element, why would it fail? curious why?

Comment: @Ben - Because DescendantsAndSelf and self will give all the Descendant nodes and self too. Other nodes doesn't contain id attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler alternative is to cast the `XAttribute` to `string` to avoid Null Reference Exception :

```cs
where (string)details.Attribute("id") == "8225706"
```